# yum install svn in linux but not working

Tags: linux

```
 yum install svn
```

Output:

> ```
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>  * addons: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
>  * base: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
>  * extras: mirror.nbrc.ac.in
>  * updates: mirror.fibergrid.in
> Setting up Install Process
> No package tomcat available.
> Nothing to do
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum install subversion
```

If it didn't help, do a `yum repolist` and see what repositories are available and if `epel` is **not** one of them, install it by `sudo yum install epel-release` and try again.